# WPF Caliburn.Micro : Life Cicyle problems

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a class called AppViewModel, this class it's responsible to control the screens. AppViewModel extends my BaseConductor:

```
public class BaseConductor : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
{
   ...
}
```

Then, I call a viewmodel (UserControl) on the constructor of AppViewModel:

```
        this.ActivateItem(new FirstViewModel());
```

On **FirstViewModel**, after the user clicks on a button I want to open  **SecondViewModel** and close the **FirstViewModel**:

```
var conductor = this.Parent as IConductor;
conductor.DeactivateItem(this, true);
conductor.ActivateItem(new SecondViewModel(param));
```

I already tried to do this:

```
((IApp)this.Parent).ActivateItem(new SecondViewModel(param));
TryClose();
```

SecondViewModel extends my BaseScreen:

```
public class BaseSceen : Screen
{
   ...
}
```

I want to close the FirstViewModel, because on the FirstViewModel and SecondViewModel I have shortcuts. When I'm with the SecondViewModel opened I hit a shortcut, and the method that is executed it's from FirstViewModel. **So, the FirstViewModel still running.**

How can I close the FirstViewModel, and avoid this problem with shortcuts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive`? You can just use `Conductor<T>` so that activating an item will automatically deactivate and close the previously active item. And also, is it required that the button/action pair reside in the `FirstViewModel`? I suggest that you just put those in the `AppViewModel` and let it orchestrate the navigation and activation/deactivation of the two child screens.

```
public AppViewModel : Conductor<Screen>
{
    public void AppViewModel()
    {
        ActivateItem(new FirstViewModel());
    }

    public void ActivateSecondViewModel()
    {
        // FirstViewModel will automatically be deactivated
        // and closed since we are using plain Conductor<T>
        ActivateItem(new SecondViewModel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a lot of screens with buttons, so I prefer they call the next screen. I edited AppViewModel to Conductor<Screen> and still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I found it! The shortcut event was attached to the window, not to the usercontrol.
So, event when usercontrol was ended the event still "attached" to the window. Now, I added an method that is called when UserControl is Unloaded, to "deattach" the event.
Bad mistake!